# Is there a written document or resource about CryptoNight v2?

Tags: cryptography, cryptonight

I am looking for something like this:

https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt

It's got a detailed, written explanation and not just code. I am trying to make a miner for learning purposes so I guess code answers like ports or different language implementations are useful too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of. The changes are quite minimal and are found in the file [slow-hash.c](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/slow-hash.c). The changes introduced are in the macros `VARIANT1_1` and `VARIANT1_2`, so if you search the linked file, you can see what they are doing and where.

There's some more information in this somewhat related question's [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/what-are-the-changes-in-cryptonight-v2-pow-algorithm) too.